# SQL INSERT performance for large data inserts (> 4,000,000)

Tags: java, mysql, xml

I encountered a problem with inserting a large amount of data into a table.

I have data in an xml file ranging in size from **40 MB to 3 GB**. Parsing the data takes 3 minutes at worst. **Inserting data into a table for a 700 MB file takes about 30 minutes**. This is too long, the total amount of data is about 200GB and it would take a month to insert it into the database.

##### How can I optimize the insertion?

**Important:** the data in the records may be duplicated. I use UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY when duplicating.

##### What I've tried:

- Using Hibernate and inserting in batches of 1000\5000\10000 records.
- Generate native sql and insert it. (It takes less than a second to generate each insert).
- Use LOAD XML from MySQL
- Create a temporary table, load data into it and then insert it into the main table

***Unfortunately, all these methods are too slow.***

Table in database:

```
CREATE TABLE as_apartments_params (
  id int NOT NULL,
  objectid int NOT NULL,
  changeid int DEFAULT NULL,
  changeidend int NOT NULL,
  typeid int NOT NULL,
  value varchar(8000) DEFAULT NULL,
  updatedate date NOT NULL,
  startdate date NOT NULL,
  enddate date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4,
COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PARAMS>
<PARAM ID="719546591" OBJECTID="40537945" CHANGEID="192698204" CHANGEIDEND="0" TYPEID="8" VALUE="83:00:050002:426" UPDATEDATE="2021-04-29" STARTDATE="2021-04-29" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" />

<PARAM ID="719547975" OBJECTID="40539484" CHANGEID="192698457" CHANGEIDEND="0" TYPEID="8" VALUE="83:00:050002:477" UPDATEDATE="2021-04-29" STARTDATE="2021-04-29" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" />

<PARAM ID="719548916" OBJECTID="40530716" CHANGEID="192698634" CHANGEIDEND="0" TYPEID="8" VALUE="83:00:050002:438" UPDATEDATE="2021-04-29" STARTDATE="2021-04-29" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" />

<PARAM ID="719548922" OBJECTID="40535413" CHANGEID="192698640" CHANGEIDEND="0" TYPEID="8" VALUE="83:00:050002:430" UPDATEDATE="2021-04-29" STARTDATE="2021-04-29" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" />
</PARAMS>
```

Comment: how long did each of the things you tried take?

Comment: how many records are duplicates?  seems like you might want to filter out the earlier ones before inserting

Comment: @ysth All operations took the same amount of time on average. Because of this, I cannot identify the bottleneck. 

The records are not duplicated very often. In the 3-file test, there were about 100 duplicate records out of 5 000 000 records. The total size of the files in the test was about 1 GB.

Comment: @ysth Now I thought about what would be possible to skip repetitive entries and write them in a separate table. And when the data is fully loaded already insert them. But this can slow down the insertion as before each insertion I need to check what records already exist.

Comment: How much RAM?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Is the `PRIMARY KEY` the only index?

Comment: 5M rows, 200GB -- Are you suggesting that there are hundreds of XML files?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Did you try `LOAD_XML_INFILE`?

Comment: @RickJames I have 10 GB of RAM for this. Yes here is a 99 xml files. MySQL 5.7.25. Yes i try LOAD_XML_INFILE

Comment: I would expect `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to be set to about 7G.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT IGNORE` would skip any rows that are duplicates according to any unique key (`id` in your case).

When you batched them, what did the `INSERT` look like?  Hopefully, it had thousand(s) of rows in a single `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (...), (...),  ... ;
```

That technique is probably the second-fastest.

The fastest would be to use a 5-million row CSV file with `LOAD DATA`.  But it might be the fastest since you need to convert the data into a file to write for it to read.

Or, maybe, the fastest would be

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'filename'
    REPLACE
    INTO TABLE ...
    etc.
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html  This would eliminate your need for parsing the XML.  (I have not used `LOAD XML`, so I don't know how fast it is, nor whether *your* XML tags can be accepted.  XSLT *may* be able to convert the XML if necessary.)

Do you run this load every day?  Does it "replace" the entire table?  If so, then do this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_t LIKE t;
load the data by whatever means
RENAME TABLE t TO old_t,
             new_t TO t;
DROP TABLE old_t;
```

There will be virtually zero downtime for `t`, regardless of how long the load takes.

**Duplicates**

Are the dups within the XML?  If it is within the XML, will the "better" data come last?  `INSERT IGNORE` will take care of it.

Or are they between the new data and the old data?  Are you saying that you are *adding* about 4 999 900 rows each day?  Please elaborate; I don't see what you mean.

Comment: Yes I use "INSERT INTO t (...) VALUES (...), (...),  ... ;" .I wrote in the question that I tried LOAD XML. I cant ignore duplicates. No, there will be a small update once a week. The base will be filled once.

Comment: @Gravy - Please give an example of a duplicate and explain what needs to be done for that example.  (I think I am missing something subtle here.)

Comment: @Gravy - and...  The current question is about loading the 99 big files, not about the tiny weekly updates?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't give a full example of the entry, as it requires pouring files to existing entries. As you can see in the example, the XML file has record IDs. The IDs are not generated by the base. 
Yes, the question is about loading the full base from a bunch of big XML files.

Comment: @Gravy - If there are dups, will both rows be in the same XML file?  Do you want the second one to simply override the first?  Or could they be in a different XML file?  In that case, can you load the files in an order where the "last" occurrence of an Id is the one you want?  If 'yes' to all that, then `REPLACE` is the correct option instead of `IGNORE`.

Comment: Duplicates are always in different files. There can't be duplicates in the same file. Yes, I tried using replace, the problem is not how to fill the data, the problem is that the insertion speed is very slow.

Comment: @Gravy - Use `IGNORE` and load the files in the opposite order.  (My logic here is that `REPLACE` might be implemented as `DELETE`+`INSERT`, whereas, `IGNORE` may be a simple "oops, let's skip this row".)

Comment: You are right! I will try to do the data loading in reverse order and use IGNORE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239216/discussion-between-gravy-and-rick-james).